# Ascertain drill RPM analyzing striations

Tags: drilling

This question is about core drilling in granite.

The pic below shows a granite formation that had core drilling performed on it.

Is it possible to ascertain the **RPM** of the drill that drilled the core in this piece of granite, given the following info about the **striations*** in the core:

1. Thread angle
2. Pitch
3. Pitch diameter
4. Major diameter
5. Minor diameter

[image]

Comment: Given https://www.diamondtoolstore.com/products/diamond-core-drill-bit-for-granite-wet and they recommend the angle grinder with variable speed then what do you think?

Comment: No. Different drill materials and geometries behave differently at different RPM. It's already virtually impossible to do so with a uniform piece of material, let alone something like granite.

Comment: I think you would need the feed rate

Comment: @TigerGuy Well feed-rate in terms of depth per revolution is obtainable from the striations. Feed rate in terms of depth per time, which you can't obtain, is what you would need for RPM, and more importantly surface-feet per minute.

Comment: @DKNguyen You said, "...the feed-rate in terms of depth per revolution is obtainable from the striations." Can you give the formula? I will figure out the math.

Comment: Feed rate is how much the cut is advanced per revolution. The distance between in the striations *is* the depth advanced per revolution. That's assuming consistent feed rate which it might not if it was advanced manually and not by automated mechanism.